# Error message 'addr' not understood en Supercollider 3.9

Tags: supercollider

I have been using Supercollider 3.8 for a long time and have decided to change the version to 3.9.3,
but it has brought us problems, currently the script.scd returns the following error:

```
ERROR: Message 'addr' not understood.
RECEIVER:
Instance of Function {    (0000022C4663FF48, gc=8C, fmt=00, flg=00, set=02)
  instance variables [2]
    def : instance of FunctionDef - closed
    context : Frame (0000022C45014BD8) of Interpreter:functionCompileContext
}
ARGS:
CALL STACK:
    DoesNotUnderstandError:reportError
        arg this = <instance of DoesNotUnderstandError>
    Nil:handleError
        arg this = nil
        arg error = <instance of DoesNotUnderstandError>
    Thread:handleError
        arg this = <instance of Thread>
        arg error = <instance of DoesNotUnderstandError>
    Object:throw
        arg this = <instance of DoesNotUnderstandError>
    Object:doesNotUnderstand
        arg this = <instance of Function>
        arg selector = 'addr'
        arg args = [*0]
    OSCFuncAddrMessageMatcher:value
        arg this = <instance of OSCFuncAddrMessageMatcher>
        arg msg = [*33]
        arg time = 161.0420767
        arg testAddr = <instance of NetAddr>
        arg recvPort = 57121
    OSCMessageDispatcher:value
        arg this = <instance of OSCMessageDispatcher>
        arg msg = [*33]
        arg time = 161.0420767
        arg addr = <instance of NetAddr>
        arg recvPort = 57121
    Main:recvOSCmessage
        arg this = <instance of Main>
        arg time = 161.0420767
        arg replyAddr = <instance of NetAddr>
        arg recvPort = 57121
        arg msg = [*33]
^^ The preceding error dump is for ERROR: Message 'addr' not understood.
RECEIVER: a Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to diagnose the problem is without the code that's generating the error.

By way of explanation of the error messsage:

`Message 'addr' not understood`: 
This means the method `addr` was called on something, e.g. `something.addr()` that doesn't have a method by that name.

`RECEIVER:
Instance of Function`:
This means that the "something" is a function.

So, somewhere you might be passing a function as an argument where some other type of object is expected (something that responds to `.addr`, so probably a `NetAddr` or `Server`).